# How to connect both ends of a bone chain to different parts of an armature?

Tags: bones, rigify

I'm modeling this character that wears some sort of respirator.
[image]
The idea is to have both ends of each pipe connected to the mask and backpack, regardless of the character's pose.
[image]
I've tried the Hook modifier coupled with vertex parenting on a curve, it was a disaster. So I've converted the pipe curve to a mesh and started working with Rigify's *limbs.simple_tentacle* preset. The tentacles are attached to the mask and I thought I would simply redirect them to the backpack with each pose but it's a lot harder than I anticipated.

What would be the best way to have one end of the pipe connected to the mask, the other to the backpack and having the rest smoothly redistributed between the two?

Comment: If the pipe doesn't stretch, use an IK chain.

Comment: So you mean having the pipes be deformed by an IK chain and connecting it manually to the backpack for each pose? Or is there a way to tell the end bone of the chain to stay on the backpack?

Comment: (And I don't mind if the pipe streches or not, BTW)

Comment: i highly recommend this tutorial, which i think is better than using hooks: https://youtu.be/NjjLbnG3VYc?si=-j1IVSwAGEiLWJEK

Comment: Yeah, pretty cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hook* modifiers should work fine, make sure that you select the handles of the control points of the curve, not only the control points, result (here I'm using empties but of course your hooks could be bones, more convenient to keyframe):

[image]

Comment: "make sure that you select the handles of the control points"… I was so close. Thanks a lot!

Comment: +1, although i think you have to rethink about your modelling skills - especially if i see how you model a body and a head. But maybe it is just abstract.... :D

Comment: @Chris, don't you know Picasso and cubism?

Comment: Who is cubism and where is Picasso? :D

Comment: @Chris, this character is made with MPFB and to be constantly deformed by a moving displacement as well as pixelized and on screen for a handful of seconds so your analysis based on a masked alien head and shoulders may be a bit off… if I may.

Comment: @Chris I think he was a musician and cubism is a kind of weird music

Comment: @DoctorFamine: shortly after you wrote that ...i saw it too!! :D

Comment: @moonboots: ah, that's why i hate tecno-music.... :D

Comment: @Chris Kraftwerk tho